# RetailPrice total error

Tags: java

How come when I print out the whole sale total and the retail price total it will not give the correct answer? Do i have the equations wrong?

```
public class RetailPrice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int NumofItems;
        int items;
        double WS = 0;
        double MP = 0;
        double RP;
        RP = (WS + (MP * WS));
        System.out.println("How many items do you want to process?: ");
        NumofItems = keyboard.nextInt();
        for (items = 1; items <= NumofItems; items++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the wholesale price of item " + items);
            WS = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the markup percentage for item: " + items);
            MP = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("The retail price of item " + items + " is $%.2f" + (WS + (MP * WS)));
            System.out.println();
        }
        double totalWP = 0;
        totalWP = totalWP + WS;
        System.out.println("Total wholesale price for the " + items + " items is " + totalWP);
        double totalRP;
        totalRP = RP * NumofItems;
        System.out.println("Total retail price for the " + items + " items is " + totalRP);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to get? What did you get? What did you do to try to debug this?

Comment: I'm expecting to get a total of $65.00 and im getting $45.00. I know for totalWP i need to add all 3 whole sale prices but i cant figure out the equation for that that java would accept.

Comment: Try doing your addition in the for loop instead of after. (Initialize totalWP before the loop.)

Comment: if the user enters 3 items, how would i add them together when java would recognize only of them? example: 10 for item 1, 10 for item 2, 10 for item 3 would obviously = 30, but how would i tell java to recognize them all and add them together instead of recognizing 1?

Answer (score 0):

I've moved some lines around to get the functionality you want. There are a lot of other improvements one could make, but first you need to work on the logic.

Try running this code, and pay special attention to the lines I moved. (Marked with // ***) Think about why I might have moved them, what they were doing where you had them, and what they're doing where I have them.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RetailPrice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int NumofItems;
        int items;
        double WS = 0;
        double MP = 0;
        double RP;

        System.out.println("How many items do you want to process?: ");
        NumofItems = keyboard.nextInt();
        double totalWP = 0; // ***
        for (items = 1; items <= NumofItems; items++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the wholesale price of item " + items);
            WS = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the markup percentage for item: " + items);
            MP = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("The retail price of item " + items + " is $" + (WS + (MP * WS)));
            totalWP = totalWP + WS; // ***
        }
        System.out.println("Total wholesale price for the " + items + " items is " + totalWP);
        double totalRP;
        RP = (WS + (MP * WS)); // ***
        totalRP = RP * NumofItems;
        System.out.println("Total retail price for the " + items + " items is " + totalRP);
    }
}
```